# OpenAI Gym 'CarRacing-v2' (discrete!) ValueError wrapping in TensorFlow Py-Environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror, openai-gym

I first instantiate the discrete version of the '[CarRacing v2](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/box2d/car_racing/)' environment and then want to wrap it in TensorFlow(TF):

```
env  = gym.make("CarRacing-v2", continuous = False) #discrete version wi
wenv = suite_gym.wrap_env(env)
```

I receive the following error message during execution:

```
ValueError: The gym space Box(0, 255, (96, 96, 3), uint8) is currently not supported.
  In call to configurable 'wrap_env'
```

Background: I want to use the environment for training a DQN-Agent and use TF modules for this.
I am new to TF, Gymnasium and Python, so is there any workaround for this error? Could somebody explain this error to me?